# Keras embedding layer masking. Why does input_dim need to be |vocabulary| + 2?

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

In the Keras docs for `Embedding` https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/, the explanation given for `mask_zero` is

> mask_zero: Whether or not the input value 0 is a special "padding" value that should be masked out. This is useful when using recurrent layers which may take variable length input. If this is True then all subsequent layers in the model need to support masking or an exception will be raised. If mask_zero is set to True, as a consequence, index 0 cannot be used in the vocabulary (input_dim should equal |vocabulary| + 2).

Why does input_dim need to be 2 + number of words in vocabulary? Assuming 0 is masked and can't be used, shouldn't it just be 1 + number of words? What is the other extra entry for?

Comment: The docs have been updated. if `mask_zero:True`, then `input_dim` equals the number of vocabulary +1 for the special zero masking

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the docs are a bit misleading there. In the normal case you are mapping your `n` input data indices `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]` to vectors, so your `input_dim` should be as many elements as you have

```
input_dim = len(vocabulary_indices)
```

An equivalent (but slightly confusing) way to say this, and the way the docs do, is to say

> 1 + maximum integer index occurring in the input data.

```
input_dim = max(vocabulary_indices) + 1
```

If you enable masking, value `0` is treated differently, so you increment your `n` indices by one: `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1, n]`, thus you need

```
input_dim = len(vocabulary_indices) + 1
```

or alternatively

```
input_dim = max(vocabulary_indices) + 2
```

The docs become especially confusing here as they say

> (input_dim should equal `|vocabulary| + 2`)

where I would interpret `|x|` as the cardinality of a set (equivalent to `len(x)`), but the authors seem to mean

> 2 + maximum integer index occurring in the input data.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks for the thorough answer! I wonder if we could submit a pull request for the Keras documentation to make it less misleading.

Comment: @NilsWerner  So in this example, is `max(vocabulary_indices)` the number of distinct words, or the total number of words in your data set? i.e., if `vocabulary_indexes=[1,2,...i,i,...,n-1,n]` is `input_dim=n+1` because `n` is `max(vocabulary_indexes)` or is `input_dim=n+2` because `i` occurs twice in `vocabulary_indexes` so `input_dim=len(vocabulary_indices)+1=(n+1)+1=n+2`?

Answer (score 0):

Because the input_dim already is +1 of the vocabulary, so you just add another +1 for the 0 and get the +2.

> input_dim: int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, ie. 1 + maximum integer
>   index occurring in the input data.

Comment: then the question what "input_dim already is +1 of the vocabulary"