# Why Keras Embedding layer's input_dim = vocab_size + 1

Tags: tensorflow, keras, embedding

In this code snippet from TensorFlow tutorial [Basic text classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification#create_the_model),

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1)])
```

As far as I understood, `max_features` is the size of vocabulary(with index 0 for padding and index 1 for OOV).

Also, I've done an experiment by setting `layers.Embedding(max_features, embedding_dim)`, the tutorial can still successfully run through(screenshots below).

So why do we need `input_dim=max_features + 1` here?

[image: model]
[image: training]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras embedding layer masking. Why does input\_dim need to be |vocabulary| + 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227938/keras-embedding-layer-masking-why-does-input-dim-need-to-be-vocabulary-2)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've read that question. First, that question is a little dated since Keras has updated their documentation. My understanding is that we set input_dim=|vocabulary|  + 1 if mask_zero=True. But this is not the case in my question, as the tutorial example doesn't enable mask because it simply connects the Embedding layer with a Dense layer.

Answer (score 1):

Vocabulary Size = Maximum Integer Index + 1

Example:
a[0] = 'item 1'
a[1] = 'item 2'
a[2] = 'item 3'
................
Maximum Integer Index = 2 
Vocabulary Size = 3

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question here. I am thinking here they make some mistake. They may originally want to do this for RNN with padding, such that 0 is not part of the vocabulary. So, the max_features + 1 is the input_dimension

Answer (score 0):

The example is very misleading - arguably wrong, though the example code doesn't actually fail in that execution context.

The embedding layer input dimension, per the [Embedding layer documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) is the *maximum integer index + 1*, not the *vocabulary size + 1*, which is what the author of that example had in the code you cite.

[image]

In my toy example below, you can see how the 0-based integer index works out:

[image]

[image]

Frankly, it looks like the writer just got lucky because he was using the Sequential model type and didn't need to serialize the model. In this special case, the example code worked.