# Question about input_dim in keras embedding layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

From the documentation on [tf.keras.layers.Embedding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) :

> `input_dim`:
>
> Integer. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1.
>
> `mask_zero`:
>
> Boolean, whether or not the input value 0 is a special “padding” value that should be masked
> out. This is useful when using recurrent layers which may take variable length input. If this
> is True, then all subsequent layers in the model need to support masking or an exception will
> be raised. If mask_zero is set to True, as a consequence, index 0 cannot be used in the
> vocabulary (input_dim should equal size of vocabulary + 1).

1. I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227938/keras-embedding-layer-masking-why-does-input-dim-need-to-be-vocabulary-2) but I'm still confused. If my vocabulary size is n but they are encoded with index values from `1` to `n` (0 is left for padding), is input_dim equal to `n` or `n+1`?
2. If the inputs are padded with zeroes, what are the consequences of leaving `mask_zero = False`?
3. If `mask_zero = True`, based on the documentation, I would have to increment the answer from my first question by one? What is the expected behaviour if this was not done?

Answer (score 1):

I am basically just trying to rephrase parts of the linked answer to make it a bit more understandable in the current context, and also address your other subquestions (which technically should be their own questions, according to [ask]).

1. It does not matter whether you actually use `0` for padding or not, Keras assumes that you will start indexing from zero and will have to "brace itself" for an input value of `0` in your data. Therefore, you need to choose the value as `n+1`, because you are essentially just adding a specific value to your vocabulary that you previously didn't consider.
2. I think this is out of scope for this question to discuss in detail, but - depending on the exact model - the loss values on padded positions do not affect the backpropagation. However, if you choose `mask_zero = False`, your model will essentially have to *correctly predict padding* on all those positions (where the padding then also affects the training).
3. This relates to my illustration: Essentially, you are adding a new vocabulary index. If you do not adjust your dimension, there will likely be an indexing error (out of range) for the vocabulary entry with the highest index (`n`). Otherwise, you would likely not notice any different behavior.

Comment: If my vocabulary is indexed from `1` to `n` (0 as padding) and I set `mask_zero = True`, should input_dim be `n+1` and not `n+2`, since the size of my vocabulary is `n`?